# MySQL 8: Most performant query to obtain latest version of each record

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group, mysql-8.0

We have a database with over 7 million entries, and we are struggling to find the best SQL query to obtain the latest entries for each **a** & **b** & **c** combination on each version. For instance:

```
create table my_table
(
  id                int auto_increment    primary key,
  a                 int                                  not null,
  b                 varchar(64)                          not null,
  c                 varchar(128)                         not null,
  version           varchar(64)                          not null,
  timestamp         datetime                             not null
);
```

With the following indexes:

```
/* Composite Index on a,b,c columns */
create index ix_my_table_a_b_c on my_table (a, b, c);
/* Index on version */
create index ix_my_table_version on my_table (version);
```

If we have the following data:

```
+----+---+-------+-------+---------+---------------------+
| id | a |   b   |   c   | version |      timestamp      |
+----+---+-------+-------+---------+---------------------+
|  1 | 1 | A84BS | BBK3S |    A    | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 |
|  2 | 1 | A84BS | BBK3S |    A    | 2020-01-01 01:00:00 |
|  3 | 1 | A84BS | BBK3S |    A    | 2020-01-01 02:00:00 |
|  4 | 2 | H8SSS | KKL90 |    A    | 2020-01-01 01:00:00 |
|  5 | 2 | H8SSS | KKL90 |    A    | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 |
|  6 | 3 | JKSIE | OOPW2 |    A    | 2020-01-01 02:00:00 |
|  7 | 4 | KL093 | IURYD |    B    | 2020-01-01 02:00:00 |
+----+---+-------+-------+---------+---------------------+
```

The returned rows for version **A** would be all the unique **a,b,c** combinations with `version=A` and the higher **timestamp**:

```
+----+---+-------+-------+---------+---------------------+
| id | a |   b   |   c   | version |      timestamp      |
+----+---+-------+-------+---------+---------------------+
|  3 | 1 | A84BS | BBK3S |    A    | 2020-01-01 02:00:00 |
|  4 | 2 | H8SSS | KKL90 |    A    | 2020-01-01 01:00:00 |
|  6 | 3 | JKSIE | OOPW2 |    A    | 2020-01-01 02:00:00 |
+----+---+-------+-------+---------+---------------------+
```

I have tried the following query to obtain these output, but doesn't seems to be so fast:

```
SELECT first_value(id) OVER(PARTITION BY a, b, c ORDER BY timestamp desc) latest_rows FROM my_table WHERE version='A';
```

Which would be the best query to obtain this result? Should I change the indexes to obtain a significant improvement on the previous query?

Using `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON [previous query]` retrieves the following information (I have added and index on `version, a, b, c, timestamp` as suggested by @danblack):

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "25364738.48"
    },
    "windowing": {
      "windows": [
        {
          "name": "<unnamed window>",
          "using_filesort": true,
          "filesort_key": [
            "`a`",
            "`b`",
            "`c`",
            "`timestamp` desc"
          ],
          "frame_buffer": {
            "using_temporary_table": true,
            "optimized_frame_evaluation": true
          },
          "functions": [
            "first_value"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "cost_info": {
        "sort_cost": "22646519.00"
      },
      "table": {
        "table_name": "my_table",
        "access_type": "index",
        "key": "ix_my_table_version_a_b_c_timestamp",
        "used_key_parts": [
          "version",
          "a",
          "b",
          "c",
          "timestamp"
        ],
        "key_length": "785",
        "rows_examined_per_scan": 22646519,
        "rows_produced_per_join": 22646519,
        "filtered": "100.00",
        "using_index": true,
        "cost_info": {
          "read_cost": "453567.58",
          "eval_cost": "2264651.90",
          "prefix_cost": "2718219.48",
          "data_read_per_join": "682G"
        },
        "used_columns": [
          "id",
          "b",
          "a",
          "c",
          "timestamp",
          "version"
        ],
        "attached_condition": "((0 <> `my_db`.`my_table`.`version`) = 'A')"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include `EXPLAIN {query}`? Does `last_value` and not including `desc` help? A `version`,`a`,`b`,`c`,`timestamp` index might be more optimal as the filtering to `version='A'` comes first however I've limited experience in seeing how window functions use indexes. Approximately how much of the table is `version=A`?

Comment: Hi @danblack I have added the EXPLAIN output after adding your suggested index, it actually increases the speed in about 20%.
Version `A` is about 3% of the whole table.

Comment: Interesting.. actually changing the order of the index to `timestamp, a, b, c, version` seems to be 44% faster.  I guess that's why MySQL recommends to use the column with higher cardinality first in the indexes.

Comment: *obtain the latest entries for each a & b & c combination on each version* If this is the only task I'd recommend covering index. `(version,a,b,c,timestamp,id)` seems to be the most suitable.

Comment: Sounds like a "groupwise max" problem.  See the tag I added.  Or http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max